# Get column value from the column that is dynamically selected depending on row value of another column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, extract

I have a dataframe as below.

```
        month   fe_month_OCT    re_month_APR    fe_month_MAY    
0       OCT     1               1               2               
1       APR     4               2               2               
2       MAY     1               4               3
```

Im trying to create a new column that gets me the value from any of the fe_month_ or re_month_ columns based on what month the row of data corresponds to (for the SAME month however we will not see 2 columns - i.e. we will never see both fe_month_APR and re_month_APR in the same df - it will either be fe or re).

Output example - for the first row, I would want this new column to have the value coming from fe_month_OCT, because month=OCT, for the second row, the value should come from re_month_APR etc.

Expected output:

```
        month   fe_month_OCT    re_month_APR    fe_month_MAY    d_month
0       OCT     1               1               2               1
1       APR     4               2               2               2
2       MAY     1               4               3               3
```

Code to create input dataframe:

```
data = {'month': ['OCT', 'APR', 'MAY'], 'fe_month_OCT': [1, 4, 1], 're_month_APR': [1, 2, 4],'fe_month_MAY': [2, 2, 3] }  
db = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all the column names are in the form "fe_month_" plus the string in `db["month"]`, you can use [apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).

```
get_value = lambda row: row[ "fe_month_" + row["month"] ]
db["d_month"] = db.apply( get_value, axis=1 )
```

Comment: Thank you! This actually works beautifully. What if there was an added layer of complexity where the column names could either be re_month_OCT or fe_month_OCT. There is only a possibility of the first letter being different (f or r) so might have to use regex somehow in the lamba function.

Comment: I've updated the question to reflect the same.

Comment: You could change the lambda function to `get_value = lambda row: row[ "fe_month_" + row["month"] ] if "fe_month_" + row["month"] in row.index else row[ "re_month_" + row["month"] ]` if the only two options are "fe..." and "re...". You could also make get_value a more complicated function (doesn't have to be a lambda function) if you need to handle more cases.